# Grid view selected index should be and its respective value should be displayed in form view

Tags: asp.net

The respective column of selected index should be displayed in form view or display view and the result should be displayed in the same page

Comment: Huh? Whats the question? And what have you tried?

Comment: the selected index of a gridview should be binded to a form view and the result should be displayed in the same page